# where is the error in the update function?

Tags: django, ajax, forms, runtime-error

i have  django project that includes a form  to be submit and allow user to create an update the stored data.

the problem is that  once the user go the update page the system crash and display the below error :

> local variable 'suspect' referenced before assignment

## urls.py

```
 path('update/<int:pk>/',update,name = 'update'),
```

## update.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block body %}

<body>


  <div class="lines">
  <div class="line"></div><div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div><div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div><div class="line"></div><div class="line"></div>
  </div>

  {% for member in instance %}
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id='left-column-Input' class="formInput" include="select()"> 
      <div class="forminputs">
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" autocomplete="off" required />
          <label for="fname" class="label-name">
            <span class="content-name" name="fname">{{member.member_name}}</span>
          </label>
      </div>

    <div class="forminputs">
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" autocomplete="off" required />
      <label for="lname" class="label-name">
        <span class="content-name" name="lname">{{member.member_last_name}}</span>
      </label></div>
    <div class="forminputs">
      <input type="text" id="fatherName" name="fatherName" autocomplete="off" required />
      <label for="fatherName" class="label-name">
        <span class="content-name" name="fatherName">{{member.member_father_name}}</span>
      </label></div>
    <div class="home-Button">
      <button id="edit" name="edit" type="submit">Edit</button>
      <button id="clear" name="clear" type="submit">Clear</button>
    </div>
    </div>

{% endfor %}

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){                           
      $("#edit").on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        fName=$('#fname').val()
        lName = $('#lname').val()
        fatherName = $('#fatherName').val()

        $.ajax({
              url:'/blog/update',
              method:'POST',

          data: {
                FName: fName,
                LName: lName,
                FatherName: fatherName,
              },

              headers:{
                'X-CSRFToken':'{{csrf_token}}'
            }
          }).done(function(msg){
              location.href='/blog/list'
          }).fail(function(err){
            alert(err)
        })
      })
    })
  </script>
</form>

</body>
{% endblock %}
```

## views.py

```
   def update(request,pk):
   #deny anonymouse user to enter the  detail page
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect("login")
    else:
      member = member()# the class modal
      member = get_object_or_404(member, pk=pk)standard **page not found**
      if request.method =="POST":
        member = member()
        member.member_name = request.POST['FName']
        member.member_last_name = request.POST['LName']
        member.member_father_name = request.POST['FatherName']

        member.save()

      context = {
        "title":member.member_name,
        "instance":member,
      }

    return render(request,'blog/update.html',context)
```

i will appreciate any help

Comment: `member = get_object_or_404(suspect, pk=pk)`. Where is the variable `suspect` defined? It isn't defined anywhere prior in the function, which is why you get an exception.

Comment: @solarissmoke my bad i add the variable member.
but still the same error

Comment: Adding `member` doesn't help... you still have no `suspect` variable defined anywhere in your code. That whole line also has various other syntax errors in it.

Comment: no  suspect variable is changed to member variable

Answer (score 0):

Your URL needs pk. You're not passing suspect id as pk in your context of your return statement of your view.

```
path('update/<int:pk>/',update,name = 'update'),
```

suspect.id will work as an argument to your `{% url ... %}`

Comment: but i am giving the id as an argument in the update function.

 member = get_object_or_404(suspect, pk=pk)

Comment: you need give pk in your return statement of your view as a part of context. so your context will be context = { "pk": suspect.id, "title":member.member_name, "instance":member }

Comment: Seems like you edited the original question. Now you need  to import suspect in your views.py.

Comment: in order to return back in the context i need to assign it in the ajax call right ?  to be able to get the request in the function.. and yes i import the model class